# Issue while creating proxy server using regional external load balancer and regional internet NEG

Tags: google-cloud-platform, proxy, gcp-load-balancer

I'm trying to create a proxy server using regional external application load balancer and regional internet NEG(FQDN) but facing error `503` and showing "**no healthy upstream**" when sent request to the IP address. It was working fine with global application load balancer and internet NEG. The purpose I'm trying to achieve  is to allow static external IP for whitelisting the outbound IP to the main server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Backend services provide configuration information to the load balancer. Load balancers use the information in a backend service to direct incoming traffic to one or more attached backends.

As per the [Official Google cloud document](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#backend-service) (**See the table**),Global external Application Load Balancer supports internet NEG(FQDN) **but Regional external application load balancer does not support internet NEG(FQDN) backend service.**

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I was able to configure a regional external load balancer with regional internet NEG, it's really ridiculous when GCP allow to this. Is there any way to configure the external load balancer with CloudNAT or internet NEG?